# Upper bound of group order where $g^3=e \forall g\in G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, heisenberg-group

If $G$ is a group such that $g^3=e$ for every $g\in G$, what is the upper bound for its order? I am aware of the Heisenberg group, and I cannot find a group with greater order that has this property. So I conjecture that $|G|\leq 27$. As for proving it, I am sure it has something to do with the fact that the order is bounded by $3^3$. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: $C_3 \times C_3\times C_3\times\cdots$

Comment: @MatthewTowers I didn't think of that.

Comment: If you add the constraint that the group has to be generated by 2 elements, your guess is right.

Comment: @MatthewTowers In that case, any element would be of the form $g^ah^b$ and therefore there would be finitely many elements of that form, correct?

Comment: No, not every element has that form (then there was only be 9 elements, but there are 27). You have to consider things like $ghghghghgghh$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a formula for $[F_n : V_{\{x^3\}}(F_n)]$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3183911/is-there-a-formula-for-f-n-v-x3-f-n)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about the direct product of arbitrarily many copies of $\mathbb{Z}_3$?

Comment: Understood, therefore there are infinitely many elements.

Answer (score 8):

If $G$ has exponent $3$ and is generated by $m$ elements, then $|G| \le 3^c$ with $c = m + \binom{m}{2} + \binom{m}{3}$, and this bound is best possible.

According to [this site](https://www-history.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/HistTopics/Burnside_problem.html) this was proved in 1933 independently by Levi and van der Waerden.

Comment: That's interesting...